# Using MethodInterceptor in Spring

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, spring-aop, method-interception

I have the following configuration to intercept a method and apply advice after returning from method, But, the following configuration does not work. Could you suggest on what I am missing?

```
@Service("txnEventSubscriber")
EventSubscriberImpl
...

@Resource(name="txnEventSubscriber")
    private EventSubscriberImpl subscriber;


    @Bean
    public Advice myAdvice() {
        return new AfterReturningAdvice() {
            @Override
            public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method, Object[] args, Object target)
            {
                System.out.println("inside advice");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyFactoryBean myProxyFactoryBean() {
        return new ProxyFactoryBean() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 6296720408391985671L;

            @PostConstruct
            public void afterPropertiesSet() throws ClassNotFoundException {
                setTarget(subscriber);
                setInterceptorNames(new String[] {"myAdvice"});
            }
        };
    }
```

I have the EventSubscriber which when invoked and when method is returned, I need to intercept the method call and do something... in this case, print "inside advice".

I am not seeing any exceptions, just method advice is not getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I see you have the class name as `EventSubscriberImpl` and you are injecting the same type of class. Meaning, you are not programming to interfaces. In this case, you would want to `setProxyTargetClass(true);` for your `ProxyFactoryBean` bean and put CGLIB in your project's classpath.

Secondly, you would need something like this

```
@Resource(name="myProxyFactoryBean")
private EventSubscriberImpl subscriber;
```

whenever you want to use the proxied version of your `EventSubscriberImpl`. Meaning, you need to explicitly get that proxied bean by its proxied bean name.

Thirdly, I'd use something like this, to avoid getting the bean by its proxied name:

```
@Resource(name="txnEventSubscriber")
private EventSubscriberImpl subscriber;

@Bean
public Advice myAdvice() {
    return new AfterReturningAdvice() {
        public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method, Object[] args, Object target)
        {
            System.out.println("inside advice");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Advisor myAdvisor() {
    AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
    pointcut.setExpression("execution(public * com.foo.bar.EventSubscriberImpl.*(..))");
    return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, myAdvice());
}
```